# Changing the colour of text inside text boxes

Tags: dashboard, templates

As standard after a new install on backdrop, the text on dashboards and some help text is white on a very light background, meaning you can't see it very well.

How would I change the colour of the text to Black or blue?
I had a quick look in the css and found I could do it, but I don't know where it is stored or if that would only affect the single page when I need the change to be site-wide.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/theme/

If this is happening with a default installation, I suggest you [create a gitlab issue](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues). It would be great if you can also do a PR but if not, include whatever proposed CSS fixes you have in the issue ticket.

To override the default CSS you can go to `Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs` and set the 'Custom CSS URL' to eg `[civicrm.files]/css/civicrm.extra.css` and then put your CSS changes in that file.

You might want to look at some of the [alternative themes](https://civicrm.org/extensions?title=&body_value=&field_extension_civi_use_target_id=356)